# mysql: recover database from frm files

Tags: mysql, xampp, data-recovery

At some point my MAMP installation became corrupt and I decided to move to XAMPP instead. However I now can't get my databases across. Other people have said I simply need to copy the DB files to XAMPP but this only partially work.

I can see the databases however all the tables have message "in use" and if I try to query a table I get the message "#1017 - Can't find file: './data_ms/geo_calendars.frm' (errno: 13)"

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Check the ownership of the files (geo_calendars.frm along with .myd and .myi should be owned by MySQL)

2) Check read/ write permissions.

3) Restart MySQL

Comment: beautiful, thank you! downloading batchmod made it easy to change ownership